# 403 Access is forbidden to the requested page errors on my website

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ssl-certificate, cpanel, http-status-code-403

I activate the SSL certificate and enable force redirection via c-panel to https but now my websites didn't open it says 403  Access is forbidden to the requested page errors on my website.

But when i disable force redirection then it works but only for http not for https.
HTTP works but HTTPS not working.

i also check permissions 644 for file and 755 for directories.

and here is the code in my .htaccess file

```
#Custom default index page
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

I also add these lines but didn't work

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

when i add these lines in .htaccess file the https urls shows something related to the server/domain hostpapa.

when i click on my website url it redirect me to https urls from http but it shows nothing just 403 forbidden error.

Comment: when i stop redirection and remove RewriteEngine On ...... code it works fine but its http not secure i want it to be https

Comment: It sounds like you have an error with the HTTPS configuration, since you can't access `https://....` URLs. Do you have access to the sever config? (Although if you are using cPanel then I guess not?) "enable force redirection via c-panel" - what does this do if it doesn't add directives to `.htaccess`?

Comment: please help me out to fix this...!

Comment: SSL certificate install successfully but https url not working...